# Using ZonalStats in QGIS 3.0.2

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I'm using the above mentioned QGIS version, and it somehow does not include ZonalStats plugin. I installed ZonalStats 0.0.4, but plugins now says this is designed for QGIS 1.7.2-1.99 and does not work for me. Is there a way to get hold on Zonal Stats?

Answer (score 8):

If you wrote zonal in the Processing toolbox search, you will find many:

[image]

The zonal Statistics is the second one from the top.

Comment: That's weird, in my QGIS (3.2.1), I cannot find the "Processing Toolbox" in the view panes available... maybe my version is corrupted or something went wrong... Or do you have an alternative to open it ?